# Creating an spl token account to be used as a signer for another instruction

Tags: spl-token

I was wondering if anyone knew how I could use the spl-token library to create an associated token account that would then be able to sign a transaction?

For example if i used spl.getAssociatedTokenAddress() to create such an account it only returns the publicKey (is this because program derived addressed do not have a keypair?)
But i wish to use this account to sign the execution of an instruction later on, but the call of my back end function only takes a keypair for the signer field...

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible.

You are right in inferring that associated token accounts are PDAs ([src](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/54695b233484722458b18c0e26ebb8334f98422c/associated-token-account/program/src/processor.rs#L127)). PDAs can only be used to sign instructions by their owner, which is in this case the associated token program.

What *is* possible is creating a regular keypair-controlled account, creating an associated token account for that account, and then signing other transactions with the keypair-controlled account.